# Minimize $\sum_i \arccos(v_i\cdot x)^2$ subject to the constraints $\|v_i\|=1$ and $\|x\|=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

**Some background: (skip to the end for the actual question)** Recently I have been trying to define some notion of an average of points on the surface of a sphere.

My original idea was to ignore the fact that the points are on a sphere and just find the vector $x$ such that the distance to all the other points squared $D=\sum_i\|v_i-x\|^2$ is minimized. Assuming $x$ must also lie on the sphere I expanded and simplified to get 
$$x=\frac{\sum_iv_i}{\|\sum_iv_i\|}$$
Doing some simulations though, I found that this definition was unsatisfactory.

Instead I found the following alternate definition worked better: Let us denote the average to be the point $x$. Then $x$ is the point such that the sum of the distances *along* the surface to the other points squared is minimized i.e.
$$D=\min_{\|x\|=1}\sum_idist_{S}(v_i,x)^2$$
where $dist_S(v_i,x)$ is the length of the geodesic between $v_i$ and $x$ on the surface $S$.

Since we are working on the sphere however, the distance function is a rather nice and simple:
$$dist_S(v_i,x)=\arccos(v_i\cdot x)$$
It follows from the fact that a geodesic on the sphere is an arc and that 
$$v_i\cdot x=\|v_i\| \|x\|\cos\theta=\cos\theta$$
**My question:** does there exist a closed form for the vector $x$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_i\arccos(v_i^T x)^2$
is minimized? If not, is there some other way of determining what $x$ is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not expect a closed form in a minimization problem with non-unique solution. E.g., if $v_i$ are the vertices of inscribed tetrahedron, then (on the grounds of symmetry) there are multiple minimizers. If $v_i$ are perturbed slightly, any of them can become the unique minimizer. Hence, $x$ is not a continuous function of $v_i$.

The key term is *Karcher mean* (sometimes *Fréchet mean*). Searching for "Karcher mean on the sphere" leads to the paper [On the Computation of the Karcher Mean on Spheres and
Special Orthogonal Groups](http://labvis.isr.uc.pt/robomat/papers/T1_2.pdf) by   Krakowski, Hüper and Manton. They avoid the aforementioned non-uniqueness  issue by assuming the points lie in a not-too-large open ball. Under this assumption, they show the convergence of an iterative argument.

Comment: What if you restrict it such that all the $v_i$'s lie on the upper hemisphere?

Comment: @E.O. That's what they do: the "not-too-larghe open ball" to which I referred is an open hemisphere.